# Align ul list with span?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm trying to align a span with ul as in my design:
Design:
http://screencast.com/t/ErEgjMtT

Here is my site, please have a look at the butom.
http://themebia.com/wp_themebia/

Not sure, what is going wrong to align copyright text with footer menu as show in design? Any tips will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It is difficult to give you answer when all you provide is a screen cast. It could be any number of things causing elements in the page not to align on the same line.

Comment: it's the padding on the `ul#footer-nav li a` css

Comment: Please check http://themebia.com/wp_themebia/ for full code

Answer (score 2):

See the below css rules for solution:

```
<div class="col-left">
<span style="padding: 12px 0px; float: left;">&copy; 2013 Themebia.  </span>
<ul>....</ul> /* footer links */
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure both tag are in `display: block;` and have the same height (height, padding, margin)
 **Currently**: your span is in `display: inline;`
**should be**: `display: block; height: 1em; padding: 1em 0;`